# Exception thrown with DataTable ReadXml

Tags: c#, exception, datatable, readxml

I have dataTable and I save it to file using `DataTable.WriteXml`

But when I try to load it using `DataTable.ReadXml` I get an exception:

> Invalid Operation exception DataTable does not support schema interface from Xml

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code your using?

Comment: I have found out what's the problem

Instead of using 

    table.WriteXml(fileLocation)

You have to use

    table.WriteXml(fileLocation, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, true);

and then when you try to load Xml file using table.ReadXml() everything works fine :)

Comment: I'm blocked from posting answers as I'm not registered user. Could someone post it as replay?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [DataSet.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx).